# Python generator missing a value during iteration

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, iterator, generator

Hello while using generators in my code, I noticed this strange behaviour where after breaking out from the loop, the `next()` call on a generator skips one value. Example code:

```
from itertools import cycle

def endless():
    yield from cycle((9,8,7,6))

total=0
e = endless()
for i in e:
    if total<30:
        total += i
        print(i, end=" ")
    else:
        print()
        print("Reached the goal!")
        break

print(next(e), next(e), next(e))
```

This outputs:

```
9 8 7 6 
Reached the goal!
8 7 6
```

Why does it skip printing `9` after breaking out from the loop. I was expecting it to print the following instead:

```
9 8 7 6 
Reached the goal!
9 8 7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing `9` is the value of `i` on the last loop iteration.  On that iteration, `i` is `9`, but the loop exits without printing it.  The next value is then `8`.

You can fix it by always printing the current value within the loop:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from itertools import cycle

def endless():
    yield from cycle((9,8,7,6))

total=0
e = endless()
for i in e:
    total += i
    print(i, end=" ")

    if total >= 30:
        print()
        print("Reached the goal!")
        break

print(next(e), next(e), next(e))
```

This produces:

```
9 8 7 6 
Reached the goal!
9 8 7
```